# How to sort a 2-d array based upon column of dates in ascending order

Tags: java, comparator, date-sorting

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;

//Class  that returns a string columnn in ascending order

public class DateCompare implements Comparator {

    int columnToSort;
    DateCompare(int columnToSort) {
        this.columnToSort = columnToSort;
    }

    //overriding compare method
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        Date[] row1 = (Date[]) o1;
        Date[] row2 = (Date[]) o2;
        //compare the columns to sort
        return row1[columnToSort].compareTo(row2[columnToSort]);
    }
}
```

My 2-D array stores phone names and their Dates of manufacture.
Friends,I have made a class named DateCompare that sorts 2-D array of records based upon column that stores dates.
This is not giving the desired output.Can anyone rectify this or give a better substitute solution because i couldn't find a clear answer on any site?
Thanks in advance!!!

input(for example):

```
Samsung                   01/01/2014
iphone                    09/02/2006
Motorola                  16/06/2009
```

Output:

```
iphone                    09/02/2006
Motorola                  16/06/2009
Samsung                   01/01/2014
```

Comment: I don't see how "Samsung" could be in a `Date[]`. Show us how you declare your variables and how you use your comparator. And use generics: If you want to sort Bananas, the comparator should be implement `Comparator<Banana>`. Also, you shouldn't use arrays to store information. You should probably have a `List<Phone>`, where `Phone` is a class having a `name` and a `date` fields.

Comment: Why don use existing jdk metods? java.util.Arrays.sort(Object[]) sorts Array of comparable objects

Comment: @agad: arrays are not comparable. To sort them, you use Arrays.sort() and pass a comparator. The above code is the comparator.

Comment: I have a 2-d array that stores phone along with their dates of manufacture.This is my question dude.

Comment: Easiest way would be to use a TreeMap<Date,String> and be done with it (semantically not the best way, but neither is a 2d array, so...)

Comment: @maczikasz: a TreeMap wouldn't accept equal dates.

Comment: @JBNizet right, didn't realize that was a requirement, but yeah why not :)

Comment: @user3383200: please answer the questions you're being asked. You're telling you store phones and dates in a 2D array, but I don't see any 2D array in your code. All I see is Date[] arrays. And a phone name doesn't fit in a Date[].

Comment: @JBNizet Dates are comparable; in the code above I see 2 arrays of dates.

Comment: @agad: Dates are comparable. Arrays of dates aren't.

Answer (score 0):

Why a 2D array, why not write a class to hold your data in a structured manner?

```
public class MyTuple implements Comparable<Date> 
{
    String phone;
    Date date;

    @Override 
    public int compareTo( Date d )
    {
         return d.compareTo( this.date );
    }
}
```

and use a `List<MyTuple>` instead of an array? I believe it was Joachim Sauer on this site that taught me the phrase "object denial" of which this is a good example :-)

Cheers,

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: dude, every date has a phone related to it and vice versa.So i want their counterparts to be with them.

Comment: @user3383200: and? why use an Object[] to store a phone name and a date, rather than using a Phone object having a name and a date fields? Java is an OO language. Use objects.